# Full disk issue but there is available space

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

After knowing my first and only Ubuntu computer is damaged in the boot section by I don't have an idea why, and getting recommendation to move my data to a fresh installation (it still boots and works fine, except I can't upgrade anymore to newer Ubuntu versions, I'm stuck with 16.04), I decided to first take a "secure way" to do it, based in some videos and investigation I done surfing the web, and installed VirtualBox on my computer, installed an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system on a virtual machine, and when trying to install some software, there is an alert that my disk is full and there is not space, but in Disks it says I have a lot of space free (much more than the 4GB there is already used). I read about some problems with "space not allocated", but in the Disk program says I have all my free space in a 211 GB "ext4" partition (and yes, my main hard drive have a lot of free space available too, near 500 GB after I made the virtual machine). When I installed the virtual machine, Ubuntu asked me about something called "LVM" to make "easier" to manage my disks, but I'm not getting a very "friendly" experience with it…

I don't have dual boot neither another computer to try on it, and obviously I don't want to lose my data. I already have a disk with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (I got it in a magazine) and a pendrive with my most important data stored, but I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu and get a non-sense problem with "no space left on disk" after installing and copying only 4 GB of data. Can you help me?

There is the output of `df -h | grep ^/`:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3,9G  3,2G  545M  86% /
/dev/loop0                          89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop1                          57M   57M     0 100% /snap/powershell/34
/dev/loop2                          87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/sda2                          976M  145M  764M  16% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  6,1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
```

This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 88,4 MiB, 92733440 bytes, 181120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 57 MiB, 59719680 bytes, 116640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 86,9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 512 GiB, 549755813888 bytes, 1073741824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 644FA88C-CC68-4888-B434-AFCB3B698E18

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    3147775    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3147776 1073739775 1070592000 510,5G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And this is the output of `vgdisplay -v`:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <510,50 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              130687
  Alloc PE / Size       1024 / 4,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       129663 / <506,50 GiB
  VG UUID               mbiIH0-9zwI-n3tk-eJ3k-Rh7Q-wD7E-QkLa03

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                RlOC9o-3Eso-5rV2-N283-DCa2-fHfO-Fo0Ga0
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2019-06-19 22:56:57 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4,00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Physical volumes ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3     
  PV UUID               T1Bo9k-LO1s-0w4E-MODj-9Mm0-9OrX-qjZ8zk
  PV Status             allocatable
  Total PE / Free PE    130687 / 129663
```

Comment: You should post the output of `df -h | grep ^/`, ...not as picture. As is, the question has no info we can work with.

Comment: Also `sudo fdisk -l` and `vgdisplay -v` output may be helpful...

Comment: Ok, I will put it in comment here

Comment: I'm not an expert on Ubuntu. I used to have a friend who done all the "tech stuff", but he is now studying in another country, and he is online at midnights, so I'm not very able to talk with him.

Comment: What size of disk you created in VirtualBox?

Comment: 512 GB. I have a real hard drive of 1 TB, but I have a lot of free space, so I made one big to check if I can move all my data to the virtual machine, and after "master" this process, do it in real world

Comment: I really don't understood the partition window of the installation because I was not understanding how Ubuntu makes the partitions, so I saw "easy management" on the LVM option, and said "Ok, is fine to me", and continued with default settings

Comment: Really, I had no problem with my computer until the last Ubuntu upgrade when I got stuck with problems with "EFI partition" and I can't upgrate Ubuntu or even update my programs because every single time I try it fails

Comment: A local friend suggested to buy a new hard drive and put it in replacement of the actual one, and in case things go wrong, swap the disks, but that means to open the laptop, and... I can't be without computer many days and I'm afraid to damage internal components...

Comment: It seems that your logical volume is very small and you have a lot of empty space in the volume group. You should `lvextend` it and then extend the root file system.

Comment: Which one is the root file system? And how I use lvextend?